# String manipulation with regex

Tags: c#, windows, regex

I have string like CAIRN-CA-200 and want to match CA with that string and want to replace
it with string.empty but it should not be replaced for CAIRN, it should replace to CA which
is joined by hypen(-). That string also can be CAIRN CA 200, then also it should be matched
with only CA word, it should not be matched with CAIRN that means string should be matched
with only to the whole word like here it is CA and should not match to the substring of any
word. How to achieve that ?

One thing is there that before and after that word there will be no any alphabetical or 
numerical character like here is hyphen.

So,one solution can be see if starting and ending of the word is not alphabet or numeric
then that word should be matched, but I don't know how to write regex for that. That is 
how to match the word that is enclosed with the character that is not alphabet or numeric ?

I tried with the thing like string `regex ="^[a-zA-Z0-9_]" + "CA" + "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]"` but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"\bCA\b", "");
```

replaces `CA` with nothing only if it is found as a whole word. `\b` is a word boundary anchor that matches only at the start or end of an alphanumeric "word".

Your regex fails because the `^` is placed outside of the character class, meaning "match at the start of the string".

If you also want to replace the surrounding characters, you could use

```
 "[^a-zA-Z0-9_]" + "CA" + "[^a-zA-Z0-9_]"
```

Inside a character class, the `^` negates the contents of the class, as you intended it too. Notice that this will fail if `CA` is at the start or end of the string.

Comment: Sorry your first regex works fine for me. This is for replacing with empty but can I check before replace it like is there @"\bCA\b" in the string CAIRN-CA- or like CAIRN-PA ? Because I have more thing to check with that string like if it contains PA word then replace it with empty,like does it contain PUT that replace PUT with empty and so on.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow. Do you want to replace `CA` and `PA` and `PUT` with empty in a single regex? No problem: `@"\b(CA|PA|PUT)\b"` will match any of those.

Answer (score 1):

```
var r = "CA";
var source = "CAIRN-CA-200";
var result = Regex.Replace(source, "([^\\w\\d_])" + r + "\\1", "$1$1");
```

This will replace any R that is not surrounded with a-z, 0-9 or _ as long as they match, the following allows for different surrounds and will match in start or end of string

```
var r = "CA";
var source = "CAIRN-CA-200";
var result = Regex.Replace(source, "([^\\w\\d_]|^)" + r + "([^\\w\\d_]|$)", "$1$2");
```

Here is my Linqpad test for the second Regex.

```
void Main()
{
    Rep("CAIRN-CA-200", "CA").Dump();
    Rep("CAIRN", "CA").Dump();
    Rep("CAIRN CA 200", "CA").Dump();
    Rep("CA 200", "CA").Dump();
    Rep("CA", "CA").Dump();
    Rep("CAIRN CA", "CA").Dump();

}

// Define other methods and classes here
string Rep(string s, string r)
{
    return Regex.Replace(s, "([^\\w\\d_]|^)" + r + "([^\\w\\d_]|$)", "$1$2");
}
```

And the results

```
CAIRN-CA-200 => CAIRN--200
CAIRN => CAIRN
CAIRN CA 200 => CAIRN  200
CA 200 => 200
CA =>
CAIRN CA => CAIRN
```